# Are there any compression algorithms that create identical files on Linux and Mac?

Tags: compression

This question and answer ([GZip doesn't produce the same compressed result on macOS vs Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/570477/gzip-doesnt-produce-the-same-compressed-result-on-macos-vs-linux)) are pretty clearly the GZIP doesn't meet the bill. No argument there.

But, I think the real question lurking behind that question is: Are there any compression algorithm that deterministically create the same binary file on Linux and Mac?

Comment: `cat`?  0% compression is abysmal, though. probably not worth bothering with.

Comment: Why you need that? I feel a strong smell of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You should simply never rely on what exactly a compression program produces, if *after decompression* the data is the same as that was compressed. What is the real problem you are going to solve?

Comment: There's a reason. I have a collection of about 5,000 binary files that, when compressed exhibit about a 40% reduction -- 100 GB to about 60GB. So compression is highly desired. A more pressing requirement, however, is that the files (either compressed or uncompressed) can be added to a content-addressable store such as IPFS -- read about it -- I wish to produce identical bit-by-bit files on different operating systems so they create identical bit-by-bit hashes when stored on a content-addressable store. Perhaps your sense of smell is a bit off? But thanks for the all-knowing question.

Answer (score 2):

I’ll restrict this to “compression *tools* that create identical files on Linux and Mac”. I know of at least one, [Lzip](https://www.nongnu.org/lzip/), which is explicitly designed for reproducibility (including across platforms); [in particular](https://www.nongnu.org/lzip/lzip_talk_ghm_2019.html),

> The lzip format does not store any metadata of the uncompressed file, except its size. Therefore, lzip files are reproducible; lzip produces identical compressed output from identical input.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks.